# Match on multiple columns using array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a project where my original dataframe is:

```
      A     B    C   label
0     1     2    2    Nan
1     2     4    5    7
2     3     6    5    Nan
3     4     8    7    Nan
4     5    10    3    8
5     6    12    4    8
```

But, I have an array with new labels for certain points (for that I only used columns A and B) in the original dataframe. Something like this:

```
X_labeled = [[2, 4], [3,6]]
y_labeled = [5,9]
```

My goal is to add the new labels to the original dataframe. I know that the combination of A and B unique is. What is the fastest way to assign the new label to the correct row?

This is my try:

```
y_labeled = np.array(y).astype('float64')

    current_position = 0
    for point in X_labeled:
        row = df.loc[(df['A'] == point[0]) & (df['B'] == point[1])]
        df.at[row.index, 'label'] = y_labeled[current_position]
        current_position += 1
```

Wanted output (rows with index 1 and 2 are changed):

```
       A     B    C   label
0     1     2    2    Nan
1     2     4    5    5
2     3     6    5    9
3     4     8    7    Nan
4     5    10    3    8
5     6    12    4    8
```

For small datasets may this be okay with I'm currently using it for datasets with more than 25000 labels. Is there a way that is faster?

Also, in some cases I used all columns expect the column 'label'. That dataframe exists out of 64 columns so my method can not be used here. Has someone an idea to improve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No one knows your desired output.

Comment: What's X in your code?

Comment: I have edited the post. Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a numpy based approach aimed at performance. To vectorize this we want a way to check membership of the rows in `X_labeled` in columns `A` and `B`. So what we can do, is view these two columns as 1D arrays (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16216866/9698684)) and *then* we can use [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to index the dataframe and assign the values in `y_labeled`:

```
import numpy as np

X_labeled = [[2, 4], [3,6]]
y_labeled = [5,9]

a = df.values[:,:2].astype(int) #indexing on A and B

def view_as_1d(a):
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    return a.view(np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[-1])))

ix = np.in1d(view_as_1d(a), view_as_1d(X_labeled))
df.loc[ix, 'label'] = y_labeled
```

---

```
print(df)

   A   B  C label
0  1   2  2   Nan
1  2   4  5     5
2  3   6  5     9
3  4   8  7   Nan
4  5  10  3     8
5  6  12  4     8
```

Answer (score 2):

Best solution is to make your arrays into a dataframe and use `df.update()`:

```
new = pd.DataFrame(X_labeled, columns=['A', 'B'])
new['label'] = y_labeled
new = new.set_index(['A', 'B'])
df = df.set_index(['A', 'B'])
df.update(new)
df = df.reset_index()
```